# Directly call globally installed Node.js modules

Tags: node.js, module, executable, npm

Supposed I want to write a module for Node.js that shall be installed globally. I do not want to write any C++ (or something else), but plain Node.js code.

Basically, this is very easy. Just write the module, and install it using `npm install -g`.

Now, most globally installed modules provide the possibility to call them directly, e.g. you can type `express` at your command prompt and run the globally installed application bootstrapper of Express.

Now my question is: How do I achieve this?

If I simply install a module globally, this does not make one of the files available as an executable, or puts that file onto the `PATH`.

What steps do I need to do in order to achieve this?

So my question is basically: What steps need to be done to create globally available executable out of a "normal" Node.js module?

Comment: I believe this is an answer — https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/package.json#L49.

Comment: @elmigranto can you elaborate on your answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to write an executable file. This is what will be executed when a user types your command. Here's an example taken from [JSHint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require("./../src/cli/cli.js").interpret(process.argv);
```

Convention says to place this file in a *bin* directory in the root of your project. You then just need to update your *package.json* file to tell it where to find your executable:

```
{
    "bin": {
        "jshint": "./bin/jshint"
    }
}
```

In this case, the executable file can be run from the terminal with the `jshint` command. When it runs, it simply requires another file and calls a method in it, passing through any command line arguments.

Comment: What are the effects if `"bin": {"jshint": "./bin/jshint"}` is missing from the package.json?

Comment: `bin` tells npm to treat mentioned files as binaries that would get symlinked into users PATH when installing with `--global` flag or under `node_modules/.bin` otherwise. In the latter case, when running `npm run` scripts, executables will be first looked up under that directory.

Comment: Here is the documentation for the `"bin"` configuration: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin