# What does "#!/bin/env" mean (at the top of a node.js script)?

Tags: node.js, openshift, declare

I found serval node.js projects that have this at top of their `app.js` (as in this [openshift program](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-mongo-node-express-example/blob/master/server.js)):

```
#!/bin/env node
```

What does this mean? How does this work? Where is it useful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366775/what-does-the-line-bin-sh-mean-in-a-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The full line from your example is:

```
#!/bin/env node
```

This simply means that the script should be executed with the first executable named 'node' that's found in your current PATH.

The shebang (#!) at the start means execute the script with what follows. /bin/env is a standard unix program that looks at your current environment. Any argument to it not in a 'name=value' format is a command to execute. See your env manpage for further details.

Comment: In general, do I need add this declare in my node app?

Comment: Only if you want to be able to start it using `./app.js` instead of needing to type `node app.js`. For an example where it's useful have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517535/directly-call-globally-installed-node-js-modules

Comment: Type 'which env' to get the path on your local system. It may be installed in /usr/bin/env instead, for example.

Comment: @chovy ... A bit late, but for osx I symlink env into bin: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/env /bin/env

Comment: @AndrewLam #!/usr/bin/env node is the right spelling.  Some platforms have /bin/env as well as /usr/bin/env, but those are typically because /bin is the same as /usr/bin.  If you're asking whether that works on only linux/unix flavors vs. windows, it depends - if you use cygwin or other flavors of , then yes, that will work, but if you just want to execute from a windows explorer window or windows command prompt (or power shell) then the #! sequence to indicator what interpreter to use won't help.  On both windows and unix, you can run 'node app.js' and whatever you have for #! is irrelevant.

Answer (score 7):

`env` is a shell command used to specify an interpreter.

Comment: In plain English that means `env` will find the location of `node` in your $PATH. 

People sometimes do `#!/bin/node` or `#!/usr/local/bin/node` but the problem is, you don't know where the person may have their copy of node. So `env` program finds that for you.