# Unable to run Node script from $PATH

Tags: node.js, npm

My Node (6.9.0) script runs without issue when I'm in the module directory and use `node bin/index.js`.

However, when I try to run it from $PATH (either via creating a `bin` entry in package.json and using `npm -g install .` or `npm link`), I'm met with the following:

```
/home/peter/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/bin/react-render-server: line 1: global.__RWR_ENV__: command not found
/home/peter/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/bin/react-render-server: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `'babel-core/register''
/home/peter/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.0/bin/react-render-server: line 2: `require('babel-core/register');'
```

Comment: are you just typing the name of the executable, or are you using `node executable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to include `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the top of your node script. See this post [What does "#!/bin/env" mean (at the top of a node.js script)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061001/what-does-bin-env-mean-at-the-top-of-a-node-js-script)